# Why doing I/O in Linux is uninterruptible?

Tags: linux, process, io, linux-kernel, sleep

What's the rationale behind it? What would the bad consequences be if a process doing I/O is allowed to handle signal?

Answer (score 4):

Now that I've read the book "The Design of the Unix Operating Systems" by Maurice Bach, let me answer this question by myself.

In short, making I/O uninterruptible is for the purpose of making the I/O task finish ASAP, without being interfered by signals.

Some related knowledge that I gained from the book:

1. The word "uninterruptible" should refer to "uninterruptible sleep". When a process is in uninterruptible sleep, it can NOT be waked up by signals, nor would it handle signals.
2. A process handles signals when: a. it is running in kernel mode and is about to return to the user mode. b. it is about to enter and leave sleep state when the sleep is interruptible.
3. What happens when a sleeping process is waken up by a signal? It would handle the signal, with the default action being exiting the process. When a process is waiting for I/O completion, you of course do not want it to exit prematurely.

Comment: Great answer. Only issue is that this doesn't answer the consequence portion of his question. What are the consequences for a premature exit?

Comment: By "It would handle the signal, with the default action being exiting the process.", do you mean that the process would be terminated? Or exit from kernel and back to userspace?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Linux Developers Documentation](http://www.lindevdoc.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_sleep), it is to prevent data loss and avoid hardware getting into an inconsistent state.

Imagine what could occur if a `read()` (such as from disk) were interruptible and the signal handler, among other duties, altered the read buffer.  Since the signal is asynchronous, the read results would not be reproducible.  Similar chaos would ensue if writing were interrupted.

Comment: But `read(2)` *is interruptible* see http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html (then you get `errno==EINTR`); however a process stays in `D` state while filesystem operations are ongoing.

Comment: Even though the process is alive after the signal interrupted read() call, there will be a loss of data as this read must have initiated data transfer from disk(hw) to kernel successfully, but not from kernel to user process(read() returns with EINTR).

Comment: The answer is not clear. Why is it a problem that "the read results would not be reproducible"? Obviously, we don't expect a well-defined, reproducible result after sending an asynchronous signal to a process.

Comment: haha well played @Wallyk....was going to add your link as a reference into my assignment

Comment: anyone can help to some me the code of linux kernel for setting the task to   uninterruptible  when doing the IO operation?