# Uninterruptable write in Linux

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, filesystems, signals

According to an answer on this question : [Why doing I/O in Linux is uninterruptible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542987/why-doing-i-o-in-linux-is-uninterruptible) I/O on linux is uninterruptible (uninterruptible in sleep). But if I start a process ,say a large 'dd' on a file and while the process is going on I forcefully unmount the Filesystem (where the file is),the process gets killed . ideally it should be in a hung state because it is sleeping and is UN.

Comment: Not sure what do you (and referenced question) mean by "uninterruptible I/O", but processing *large* amount of data is definitely can be interrupted by signals. BTW, you may interrupt `dd` process manually (e.g. with `Ctrl+C`), and the process terminates relatively fast.

Comment: I don't think `dd` will use a _single_ file operation -- more likely many small ones.

Comment: @KevinBoone: Actually, `dd` will call `write` with `bs` number of bytes, which defaults to `512`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev "uninterruptible I/O" meaning : you started an I/O say read operation(large) process initiated read and went to sleep ,waiting for response from device,So now process is in sleep and  cannot be awaken even by any signal .Hence uninterruptible..

Comment: @rodrigo -- indeed. So unless you set a huge value of `bs`, the fact that the `dd` command can be interrupted doesn't say anything about whether the read/write system call can be interrupted, only about signal handling in `dd`.

Comment: @KevinBoone: Yes, and if you do `dd ... bs=4G` and, while it is copying (or swap trashing), you unmount the filesystem where you are copying you will get the `umount` waiting for the `dd` to finish.

Comment: Sure. I've turned that into an answer. Feel free to comment if you think I've missed anything.

Comment: You're also assuming the only response possible to having the filesystem yanked out from under it is to hang forever.  Why can't the `write()` call *fail* at that point?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: because if the write() has started writing to the underlying device, but it hasn't finished yet, it cannot be interrupted, you have to wait until it finishes. That's precisely what this all is about.

Comment: *it cannot be interrupted, you have to wait until it finishes*  Really?  Why can't the `umount` operation cause pending `write()` operations to *fail*?  Just because a system call can't be *interrupted*  from user space doesn't mean it can't fail.  You're assuming a restriction placed on the user applies to the kernel itself.  It's the kernel code itself that doesn't allow the interruption in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

"Uninterruptible" applies to the low-level read/write operations handled by the kernel. In C programming, these correspond broadly to `read()` and `write()` calls on the C standard library. That a utility can be interrupted does not say much about whether I/O operations can be interrupted, because a specific file operation in a utility might correspond to many low-level I/O operations.

In the case of `dd`, the default transfer block size is 512 bytes, so copying a large file might consist of many I/O operations. `dd` can be interrupted *between* these operations. I would expect the same to apply to most utilities that operate on files. If you can force them to work with huge data blocks (e.g., specify a gigabyte-size argument for `bs=` in `dd`) then you might be able to see that low-level I/O operations are uninterruptible.

Comment: Agree with what you are saying @Kevin Boone ,and when I said I/O operations I meant system calls.There are fair chances that 'unmount' happened in between two I/Os hence it never went to sleep and got killed by signal.I am going to try 'dd' with very large block size and see how to reacts to unmount.