# Does read/write blocked system call put the process in TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE or TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, signals, system-calls

As mentioned in the man page of signal(7),

```
   Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers
       If a signal handler is invoked while a system call or library function call is blocked, then either:

       * the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler returns; or

       * the call fails with the error EINTR.

       Which  of  these  two behaviors occurs depends on the interface and whether or not the signal handler was established using the SA_RESTART flag (see sigaction(2)).  The details vary across UNIX systems; below, the details for
       Linux.

       If a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is interrupted by a signal handler, then the call will be automatically restarted after the signal handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used; otherwise the call  will
       fail with the error EINTR:

           * read(2),  readv(2),  write(2), writev(2), and ioctl(2) calls on "slow" devices.  A "slow" device is one where the I/O call may block for an indefinite time, for example, a terminal, pipe, or socket.  If an I/O call on a
             slow device has already transferred some data by the time it is interrupted by a signal handler, then the call will return a success status (normally, the number of bytes transferred).  Note that a (local) disk is not a
             slow device according to this definition; I/O operations on disk devices are not interrupted by signals.
```

As it is mentioned that a blocked call to one of the following interfaces(read, write) is interrupted by a signal handler, then the call will be automatically restarted after the signal handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used, that means in case of blocked read/write system call, process must be in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state.

But when I was trying to find out blocked system calls that put process in TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE state, I found https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62697/why-is-i-o-uninterruptible and [Why doing I/O in Linux is uninterruptible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542987/why-doing-i-o-in-linux-is-uninterruptible) , and in both the places it is mentioned that blocked I/O call(read, write) will put a process in TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE.

Also its mentioned here: https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/processstates_20120831.pdf

```
The Uninterruptible state is mostly used by device drivers waiting for disk or network I/O. When the process
is sleeping uninterruptibly, signals accumulated during the sleep are noticed when the process returns from
the system call or trap. In Linux systems. the command ps -l uses the letter D in the state field (S) to
indicate that the process is in an Uninterruptible sleep state. In that case, the process state flag is set as
follows:
p->state = TASK_UNINTERRUPTABLE
LEARN MORE: Read more about D states in the Red Hat Knowledgebase:
https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/solutions/59989/
```

It's kind of confusing.

Also I want to know other blocked system calls which can put a process in TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE state.

Answer (score 5):

With `read(2)` or `write(2)` family syscalls, the type of sleep depends on the type of file that is being accessed.  In the documentation you quoted, "slow" devices are those where a `read/write` will sleep interruptibly, and "fast" devices are those which will sleep uninterruptibly (the uninterruptible sleep state is named `D` for "Disk Wait", since originally `read/write` on disk files was the most common reason for this type of sleep).

Note that "blocking" technically refers only to interruptible sleep.

Almost any system call can enter uninterruptible sleep, because this can happen (among other things) when a process needs to acquire a lock protecting an internal kernel resource.  Usually, this sort of uninterruptible sleep is so short-lived that you will not notice it.